Running maven ktlint execution from CLI to generate text report
I'm trying to run mvn ktlint:ktlint from command-line but generate a text report instead of the default HTML report.
The text report can be generated by configuring the ktlint plugin with an execution block as follows:
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.gantsign.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>ktlint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>format</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>format</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>reporter</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                <reporters>
                    <reporter>
                        <name>plain</name>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/ktlint.txt</output>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>group_by_file</name>
                                <value>true</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </reporter>
                </reporters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

I want to generate this text report as part of a git pre-commit hook via command-line instead of keeping it as an execution block in the pom.xml.
I'm trying to replicate that execution block configuration via -D parameters, not sure if this is possible or not:
./mvnw ktlint:ktlint -Dconfiguration.reporters.reporter.name=plain

TLDR: Is it possible to pass the configuration that's in the ktlint execution block via -D parameters to get a text report or is there maybe another way to make the ktlint maven plugin generate a text report instead of an HTML report via command-line?
